# Dimnames of symmetric Matrix (package Matrix)

Tags: r

I think the behaviour of the code below is strange. Is it a bug or is it meant to be like this?  I would like to have only colnames and no rownames. But it is impossible to remove the names by assigning NULL. I used R version 3.6.2 and Matrix version 1.2-18.

**Input**

```
library(Matrix)
m <- Matrix(0, 2, 2)
colnames(m) <- c("a", "b")
m
attr(m, "Dimnames")
rownames(m)
rownames(m) <- NULL
rownames(m)
colnames(m) <- NULL
colnames(m)
attr(m, "Dimnames")
```

**Output**

```
> library(Matrix)
> m <- Matrix(0, 2, 2)
> colnames(m) <- c("a", "b")
> m
2 x 2 sparse Matrix of class "dsCMatrix"
  a b
a . .
b . .
> attr(m, "Dimnames")
[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
[1] "a" "b"

> rownames(m)
[1] "a" "b"
> rownames(m) <- NULL
> rownames(m)
[1] "a" "b"
> colnames(m) <- NULL
> colnames(m)
[1] "a" "b"
> attr(m, "Dimnames")
[[1]]
[1] "a" "b"

[[2]]
NULL
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are not using base Rs `matrix`? Because to me it almost makes sense that a symetric matrix should have always same row and col names... but maybe I'm missing the point here ;)

Comment: Yes, I am updating SSBtools::HierarchyCompute. The use of sparse matrices is extremely important. In special cases when the output matrix is symmetric, rownames looks strange.

Comment: I see that after changing elements of the matrix so that it is no longer symmetric, it becomes possible to remove the rownames by assigning NULL. This fix is a satisfactory solution for me.  It’s extremely rare that the final matrix is actually symmetric.